# css not working while using backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js and require.js to develop a web page. Now I'm stuck in a situation, anyone please help me. I want to display a `<div>` fixed at bottom of the page even scroll the cursor down. I added the  as follows:-

```
<div id="btn-scroll-up" class="footer-content btn-scroll btn btn-sm btn-inverse">
     <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-up icon-only bigger-110"></i>
</div>
```

also I created a css with a class:-

```
.btn-scroll {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

But, I'm surprised that the position fixed is not working. I'm using backbone templates and the `<div>` part contained in my template and css was loaded in index.html. Please feel free to update your thoughts regarding this.

thanks,
Jyothis

Comment: Inspect element and see if any CSS rule override it

Comment: its working fine with your given information **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ad95d/)**

Comment: there must be something else conflicting in the generated html

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your position property. It could be that backbone is overriding your CSS.

```
position: fixed !important;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But still there exist the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you could change your css class little bit like this:

```
#btn-scroll-up.btn-scroll {  /* <---use a #id.class selector */
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

---

As IDs are having highest priority then this would work because we have selected the element with combination of its ID and Class name.

Comment: ya. I done it. But no use. I'm using an external css. Is there any problem with that ? I don't know I'm working with backbone MV* architecture. So I render each view as templates in my index.html. Did you think is this cause the problem ?